# Is there an AppBar button style that means "Open in Web Browser"?

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

Is there an AppBar button style that means "Open in Web Browser"?

This seems like a pretty common scenario, so maybe there's already a Microsoft style for it. Otherwise I guess I'll have to roll my own.

Comment: [You tell me](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj841127.aspx).

Comment: There's not one in that list. Already checked.

Comment: So you already know the answer the question, yet asked it anyway?

Comment: The reason I asked is because I am hoping one already exists somewhere else.

Comment: Perhaps you should stick with one of the generic "Go", "New Window" or "Globe" styles.

Comment: Emphasize that you change the focus away from the app.  I've seen `\ue143` used for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of a perfect match, I think the best is new window:

[image]

I think it conveys what you are wanting to say here.

It's `U+E17C` in **Segoe UI Symbol**.

You can also find it in Common/StandardStyles.xaml as `NewWindowAppBarButtonStyle`

Comment: The defacto standard seems to be the 'World' icon in the StandardStyles. Many apps use this (e.g. NextGen Reader and Latermark). I think the IE logo would be a good fit also.

Comment: This seems like it conveys the message pretty well. I just changed the text to "Open Browser"

Answer (score 0):

The [Modern UI Icons](http://modernuiicons.com/) library has several icons that could be used. It contains a generic browser icon, as well as one for Chrome and IE.

I discovered this in a helpful [Tim Heuer blog post](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/10/29/use-new-appbarbutton-in-windows-8-1-commandbar.aspx) about using font icons in Windows 8.1.